# Serializing JSON object effectively

Tags: python, mysql, django, json

This is a bit of a puzzle, I have these pseudo models:

```
class Country(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(unique=True)

class Region(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(unique=True)
   country = models.ForeignKey(Country)

class SubRegion(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(unique=True)
   region = models.ForeignKey(Region)

class Estate(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(unique=True)
   sub_region = models.ForeignKey(SubRegion)
```

I am trying to JSON serialize their data as below. However i'm not sure how to do this effectively (avoiding too much database queries), suggestions are appreciated

```
{

    CountryX: { 
        RegionX {
            SubRegionX = [
                "EstateX"
                "EstateY",
                "EstateZ"
            ],
            SubRegionY = [ etc... ]
        },
        RegionY { etc... }
    },
    CountryY: { etc... }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but it should give you the idea. Start with the innermost object, use select_related to traverse the heirarchy, then loop over the innermost objects, adding the keys for the heirarchy as needed.

Just a note of warning, if there are Countries/Regions/Subregions without any estates, they won't be included in the JSON. If that's not OK, you'll need to query each of the models separately.

```
data = {}
for e in Estate.objects.select_related("sub_region__region__country"):
    sub, region, country = e.sub_region, e.sub_region.region, e.sub_region.region.country
    if country.name not in data:
        data[country.name] = {}
    if region.name not in data[country.name]:
        data[country.name][region.name] = {}
    if sub.name not in data[country.name][region.name]:
       data[country.name][region.name][sub.name] = []
    data[country.name][region.name][sub.name].append(e.name)
json_data = json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: if sub.name not in data[country.name][region.name][sub.name] should be if sub.name not in data[country.name][region.name]

Answer (score 1):

This suggestion might not be exactly what you were looking for, but I've used it in a couple of situations where I needed quick-and-dirty JSON of an app's data.

Check out[`./manage.py dumpdata app_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model) (or `app_name.model_name`). This gives you JSON for all of the data in all of the tables of that app (or that model). The format may be a little different than you were thinking about, but it does include all of the PK and class info necessary to maintain ForeignKey relationships, and it spits them out in the order necessary to create the referenced object *before* you create the referencing object. Very handy.

If you want to invoke it from inside a script, look at `django/core/management/commands/dumpdata.py` to see how they do it.